# Apache2 - Why Private Key and Certificate do not match?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, server

I want to set ssl to my server which runs with apache. So i followed the instructions given from [google](https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache/). I asked for a ssl certificate for my domain and I got the ssl-mysite.key file. **Unfortunately this is the only file i have received from my provider**.

However you need an SSLCertificateChainFile and SSLCertificateFile I found a SSLCertificateFile inside `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` tried to add this to my mysite.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/sites-pk.key
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
...
```

now apache can't start the server and throws [image: console output]

So I looked up the mysite-error.log for more informations and i got

```
[ssl:emerg] [pid 956:tid 1234567890] AH0123: Certificate and private key www.mysite.de:443:0 from /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt and /etc/ssl/sites-pk.key do not match
```

I thought maybe its because I use the port 80 in the .conf but if I change to 443 the server even doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in a proper way to run the apache successfully with SSL.

There are 3 files required to install SSL in apache.

1. Certificate file: certificate.crt
2. Certificate Chain file: ca-cerrificate.crt
3. Private Key: private.key

Before purchase a SSL, you have to generate a CSR file by filling up a form of your site name, organization name, country code etc.

During CSR generation it needs to generate a private key file also.

Save the CSR & key file in your system.

Now put the CSR file to your SSL provider, it will generate and provide you a zip file after payment.

Download that zip file and unzip it, you will get below 3 files in it

1. certificate file
2. chain certificate file
3. .pem file

Now you have to use first two files alongwith your previously saved key file in below mysite-ssl.conf file.

Keep your mysite.conf as it is, please don't put SSL certificate inside it.
Also you need to mention DocumentRoot path inside both the conf file, which you have missed here

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
#DocumentRoot as example
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
```

Make a new file like mysite-ssl.conf inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder and write as below

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
#DocumentRoot as example
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificates.crt
SSL CertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificates.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/sites-pk.key
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
```

Then make it enabled

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo a2ensite mysite-ssl.conf
```

Restart apache service

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Enjoy happy web hosting!!!